# Alternate elements of a vector with multiple NAs

Tags: r, vector

I have a character vector in R, and want to make a new vector with multiple NAs between the elements of the character vector.  To simplify, the character vector is:

```
cv <- c( "A", "B", "C" )
```

Let's say we just want 3 NAs (actually need much more). Desired output vector would be:

```
"A", NA, NA, NA, "B", NA, NA, NA, "C", NA, NA, NA
```

I'm guessing this has been asked before, but it's very difficult to search for.  I've tried various permutations and combinations of rep and rbind with no success.  Be gentle; my first question :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `sapply` to concatenate c(NA, NA, NA) to each element of `cv` so that for each element of `cv` we get a 4-vector.  `sapply` will arrange these into a 4 x n matrix (where n is the length of `cv`) and `c` on the left will unravel that matrix into a vector.

```
c(sapply(cv, c, rep(NA, 3)))
##  [1] "A" NA  NA  NA  "B" NA  NA  NA  "C" NA  NA  NA
```

Comment: Thank you.  I've never understood those apply functions but I guess I need to work harder at it.  I'm choosing this as answer because it seems (to me) a bit more straightforward than the other.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to play it with `matrix()` and `as.vector()`

```
v <- as.vector(rbind(cv,matrix(nrow = 3,ncol = length(cv))))
```

such that

```
> v
 [1] "A" NA  NA  NA  "B" NA  NA  NA  "C" NA  NA 
[12] NA
```

Answer (score 1):

We could create a vector with `NA`'s and replace `cv` elements based on position generated by `seq`.

```
n <- 3
vec <- rep(NA, (n + 1) * length(cv))
vec[seq(1, length(vec), n + 1)] <- cv
vec
#[1] "A" NA  NA  NA  "B" NA  NA  NA  "C" NA  NA  NA
```